# Get all rows from dynamical table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-tables

I am trying to read all rows from a dynamic table. The main idea is to read all the rows and store it in an array for further processing. But so far I have not been able to get the row data.  The code below only returns the table headers.

Here is the code:

```
var data = [];

var i = 0;

$('#tempTable td').each(function (index, tr) {
    var tds = $(tr).find('td');

    if (tds.length > 1) {
        data[i++] = {
            action: tds[0].textContent,
            spec: tds[1].textContent,
            data: tds[2].textContent,
            unit: tds[3].textContent,
            upper_tol: tds[4].textContent,
            lower_tol: tds[5].textContent,
            tol_unit: tds[6].textContent,
            def: tds[7].textContent
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML markup looks like this:

```
<table id='tempTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class='table_head' width='80px'>Header1</td>
            <td class='table_head' width='435px'>Header2</td>
            <td class='table_head' width='100px'>Header3</td>
            <td class='table_head' width='100px'>Header4</td>
            <td class='table_head' width='100px'>Header5</td>
            <td class='table_head' width='100px'>Header6</td>
            <td class='table_head' width='100px'>Header7</td>
            <td class='table_head' width='80px'>Header8</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Rows inserted dynamically here using jQuery -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the event that is triggered to get the rows? And get the tbody trs instead of the table's tds

Comment: your selector has td when you are trying to look up rows $('#tempTable td') change to $('#tempTable tr'), also when are you calling that snippet of code?

Comment: That's because, your code runs before any update happens in the tbody section of your page, probably!

Comment: `$(#tempTable')[0].rows`?

Comment: try `console.log("text");` to debug your code and see in the browser console where your data is being appended and the function you pointed out here. **Note the sequence** in which these logs appear

Comment: @mplungjan The code is in a function, which is called by another function. The other function is coming from an `<a></a>` tag from the `onclick="myFunction()"`

Comment: @WalksAway I have tried this, and I still only have the headers of the table. Also, see my comment about calling the code.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized your table headers as 'td' instead you need to initialize them in 'th' as below..

```
<table id='tempTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='table_head' width='80px'>Header1</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='435px'>Header2</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header3</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header4</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header5</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header6</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header7</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='80px'>Header8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Rows inserted dynamically here using jQuery -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also see the at which event you are selecting table data(Before selection table should be filled with data).

For selecting the data from table :

```
//traverse each row
$('#tempTable tr').each(function (index, tr) {
    var cols = [];

    //get td of each row and insert it into cols array
    $(this).find('td').each(function (colIndex, c) {
        cols.push(c.textContent);
    });

    //insert this cols(full rows data) array into tableData array
    tableData.push(cols);
  });

  console.log("tableData: ", tableData);
```

Please find the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/frm2ebug/1/ for the same..

Comment: 1. You can put TDs in THEAD.   2. You've not mentioned to update the script to `$(tr).find("th")` so even if it did work, this would mean it wouldn't work 3. The issue is a simple typo `$("td").find("td")`

Comment: Yes we can put td in headers. But he is selecting ' td'  for data retrieval so the headers will be coming under the data  if we keep them under td..

Comment: That comment doesn't make any sense (sorry).

Comment: @freedomn-m I have tried your solution with `$("td").find("td")` but it didn't work.. Can you post an answer with the full proposed correction?

Comment: @PrakashThete I have tried your proposal and it doesn't solves the problem. I am still getting `undefined` when I try to print out the first element of the array.

Comment: Added the JSFiddle please have a look. Let me know if problem persist.

Comment: @PrakashThete Thank you, it is working now! Is there any ways to split the string into pieces? Right now I have a string with `,value#1,value#2,value#3, etc..` I would like to have `value#1` (and also the others) by itself.

Comment: Hi @MikaelKP you can accept/upvote the answer if you think it has helped you. If you have doubts please ask a new question or edit your question so that me or anyone else can also give their input.

Comment: As per @walksaway 's comment, your issue was the selector - I was showing what was wrong, you only had to change your original code to `$("tr").find("td")`